# Re-encode video stream only with ffmpeg (and with all audio streams)

Tags: audio, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to re-encode the video stream of a movie only and keep all other streams as they are using `ffmpeg` or more specific `streamio/streamio-ffmpeg` ([Github - StreamIO-FFMPEG](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)).

I already tried various combinations of `-map 0` or `-map a:0 -map s:0`, but in all combinations I tried, either nothing is encoded at all, or not all other streams are copied to the new file. In most cases there is only one audio stream after encoding, when there were two before, and sometimes the subtitle streams are lost, too. Also most times the info what language the streams are in gets lost.

So when I have a movie file (mkv) with the following streams:

```
0: video [H.264, 1080p]
1: audio [english, mp3]
2: audio [french, mp3]
3: subtitle [english (forced)]
4: subtitle [english]
```

What should the `ffmpeg` parameters be, if I want to encode the video file to `H.265` and `720p` and keep all other streams as they are?

What should the parameters be, if I additionally want to encode the audio streams as `AAC`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf scale=hd720 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 out.mkv
```

To encode audio as well,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf scale=hd720 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 -c:a aac out.mkv
```

(The order of the arguments above matter)

Comment: It works nicely. Thank you very much. Could you tell me where and how I put an explicit scaling like `1920x1080` as a parameter?

Comment: Use scale=1920x1080

Comment: I also tried to convert an `mkv` file to `mp4` but it fails with the message `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`. The video is `mkv, H.264, 1280x720, AC3` and my parameters are `-i <FILENAME>.mkv -vf scale=1280x720 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -c:a aac <FILENAME>.mp4`

Comment: MP4s only accept mov_text subtitles. I bet your subtitles aren't. Drop the `-c copy`

Comment: Is it possible to convert the subtitles, too? Or can I explicitely drop them? With something like `-c:s none` or something? I'm writing a script that decides on a per-video base. So some files might already have the right video codec, so I want to copy that to the new file (therefore keep `-c copy`). Related to that: Is there a difference between `-c copy` and `-c copy -c:v libx264 -c:a aac` if my video file is already in `H.264` and `AAC`?

Comment: For subtitles, you can use `-c:s mov_text`. To drop all subs instead, add `-sn`.   `-c copy -c:v libx264 -c:a aac` will copy all streams except video and audio and encode video as H.264 and audio as AAC. Doesn't matter what the source codecs are.